# How to show a dialog box a software using java when the software run 1st time in that system

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-8

In my software I want to show  a message "welcome " in joptionpane when the application run 1st time in that system. I do not want this message in 2nd or any more time. Only required in once when the application run 1st time in that system using netbeans .

Comment: You can use a file, lets say settings.conf, in which you can have a property show.splash.screen = 0. 
In your app, first you check this property, if is 0 you display the splash screen and update the property in the file show.splash.screen = 1. 
Next time when your apps starts it will not display the splash screen.

Comment: this is not in android it is using for desktop application.

Comment: I tried so many website to check the code but I was not able to see any codes.

Comment: You can still include a settings file with a desktop application.

Comment: @JackDeeth can I get the code ?

Comment: Rather than a file, I would use [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) for this.

Comment: @VGR so which is good in Preferences . I found there so many things . so can you please help me for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probaby a good use case for [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html):

```
Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(getClass());
boolean hasRunBefore = prefs.getBoolean("hasRunBefore", false);
if (!hasRunBefore) {
    prefs.putBoolean("hasRunBefore", true);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainWindow,
        "Welcome to ExampleApp!", "Welcome",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
        applicationIcon);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file in somewhere in system (for example in user home directory), only create this file if not exist.

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/.launch_first_time");

if(!file.exist()) {
file.createNewFile();
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "welcome", "Launch for the first time", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

You can run this code everytime you open the application using [WindowsListener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15469938/3448799)

Comment: I found 2 errors in your code .

1. isExist() is not in netbeans instead it is Exists().

Comment: second error is there not showing that dialog box when run the application . and it is not clearly working. Please check and update the code. 

thank u